# Setting response parameter for http request

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to figure out where I would set the response body parameter url. I'm uploading a file and returning the url to the frontend like so

```
 context.res = {

        status: 201,

        body: {
          message: "Image Upload Successful!",
          url: returnedUrl
        },

        headers: {
          "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true",
          "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
          "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "POST, OPTIONS",
          "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type, Set-Cookie",
          "Access-Control-Max-Age": "86400",
          "Vary": "Accept-Encoding, Origin",
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }

      };

      context.done();
```

Normally I can do something like

```
 .post<{ url: string }>(
```

but I don't know where to put that in order to be able to access that property in the response object with my current http request. It's setup a little different than I'm used to so I'm sure where it would go. I appreciate any help!

```
 uploadFiles(file: File, userId: string, title: string, counter: number) {


    const form = new FormData();
    form.append('file', file);


    console.log("FILE OUTPUT");
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();

    headers.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
    headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
    let options = { headers: headers, reportProgress: true };

    const api = environment.azure_function_url + `/UploadFilesTest?userId=${userId}&glassTitle=${glassTitle}&counter=${counter}`;
    const req = new HttpRequest('POST', api, form, options);

    return this.http.request(req)
      .pipe(
        map((res: HttpEvent<any>) => {
          if (res.type === HttpEventType.Response) {
            return res;
          } else if (res.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress) {
            // Compute and show the % done:
            const UploadProgress = +Math.round((100 * res.loaded) / res.total);
            return UploadProgress;
          }
        })
      );
  }
```

[image]

Comment: When you invoke "uploadFiles"  it returns an Observable. You have to subscribe to that observable to retrieve the data.

Comment: I added an image showing the subscribe from my component to original question. From the pic you can see that res.url isn't recognized

Answer (score 0):

you can declare interface for upload events and map response data to new object

```js
  export interface IUploadResult {
    progress?: number;
    url?: string;
  }

  //usage
    this.uploadService.uploadFiles(this.fileToUpload)
      .subscribe((result: IUploadResult) => {
         console.log(result);
      });

  //service

  @Injectable()
  export class UploadService {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    }

    uploadFiles(file: File, userId: string, title: string, counter: number):
      Observable<IUploadResult> {

      const api = environment.azure_function_url + 
        `/UploadFilesTest?userId=${userId}&glassTitle=${title}&counter=${counter}`;

      const content = new FormData();
      content.append("file", file);

      const options: any = {
        body: content,
        reportProgress: true,
        observe: "events",
        responseType: "blob",           
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
          "Accept": "application/json"
        })
      };

      return this.http.request<any>("post", api, options)
       .pipe(
         map((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
           if (event.type === HttpEventType.Response) {
             return { url: event.url };
           }
           if (event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress) {
             const progress = Math.round(100 * event.loaded / event.total);
             return { progress };
           }
       }));
    }
  }
```

Comment: With your answer I get the following errors: https://pastebin.com/NX9VjcdK

Comment: The component isn't rendering now. This is the only error I'm getting: https://postimg.cc/xXvMJbYB  Here's all my code as a reference updated: https://pastebin.com/954vQMcF

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by changing this code from this

```
   if (res.type === HttpEventType.Response) {
            return res;
          }
```

to

```
   if (res.type === HttpEventType.Response) {
            return res.body.url;
          }
```

then I was able to capture the url in the component

```
      this.fileUpload.uploadFiles(output, this.userId, title, counter)
        .subscribe((res) => {
          console.log(res);
          let url = res;
        });
```